# Mobile website preview

Tags: android, mamp, preview, adobe-brackets

My website's desktop version is almost finish.
Now, I would like to test my website on my android device (Htc One).

I'm not looking for an emulator, because I want to test all my touching reactions.
I tried with CodeKit, by generating an url, but my smartphone don't want open the page.

Do you have any soft to recommend to do this ?
I coded with Brackets using mamp.

Hope you have understand my problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First make sure you have MAMP installed on your machine.
2. Next step is to get your IP address on your MAC > System Preferences > Network > AirPort.
3. Now you’ll need the Apache Port from MAMP. (default is 8888).
4. Put these two piece of information together to make up the URL for your iPad/iPhone: 192.168.100.170:8888.

Now go to this url with your smartphone and that's it !

http://www.designshifts.com/view-local-wordpress-website-on-your-iphone-or-ipad-with-mamp/

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Brackets, then [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/) may be a good option because it has a [Brackets extension available](http://blogs.adobe.com/edgeinspect/2013/06/20/edge-inspect-integration-with-edge-code-and-brackets/).

Edge Inspect syncs mobile devices with your desktop browser so you can test across all of them at once. And it makes it easy to connect dev tools to your mobile device for debugging the mobile rendering (although it's a slightly limited version of the dev tools, called [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html)).